# What is Daughter supposed to do?

Tags: i-am-mother

At the end of [*I am Mother*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Mother), the following seems to be the state of things:

> - Mother is dead. In fact, the AI still appears to be active and in control of at least one android body, but for sure, Daughter is not supposed to know about that. (Shooting Mother is supposed to be some closure to her, the decisive step to taking things into her own hands.)
>  - Daughter is now in charge. She is the "new Mother" (though, for the sake of clarity, I will continue referring to her as "Daughter"). She will have to oversee and trigger the gradual reawakening of the human species.
>  - There are, in all, a total of two individuals available to do anything on the base - a roughly twenty-year-old without any first-hand experience in raising children (yet - and all of Mother's experience gathered over the years is gone), and a newborn infant.

**What is Daughter supposed to do?** Presumably, the

> corn growing machines have shut down along with anything else controlled by the AI

and as far as we could see, nothing appears to be automated in the base unless it is done by the Mother robot.

Therefore:

> How is Daughter supposed to do (or at least start) the repopulation of Earth? Presumably, the base stores or grows enough food for the time being, but the corn fields outside need to be tended to or they won't be of much use in the future. Is she meant to become a farmer all alone on those vast fields? While, at the same time, raising multiple children?

Is there any indication within the movie or from behind-the-scenes material on this?

Comment: I've read this a few times and I'm really not sure what you're asking here

Comment: @Valorum: I'm asking what she is supposed to do after the end of the film. She is essentially alone in a huge base on a deserted (part of?) Earth, and the ultimate goal appears to be to repopulate Earth from the embryos stored on the base. I'm completely in the dark about how she's supposed to get there, without any help from the robots (which must at least pretend to be permanently disabled, or else her shooting of Mother would be meaningless), so I'm asking what she's supposed to do.

Comment: If the question is "how does Mother expect Daughter to be able to survive and raise/feed/care for more humans," perhaps that should more clearly expressed.

Comment: @DavidW: I tried to ask a question that would not contain any spoilers, because hiding the question in a spoiler area seems questionable to me. I'll include this more concrete version in the spoilers, though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Why would the robots need to pretend to be disabled?

Comment: @Valorum: Because Daughter knows they are essentially Mother/controlled by Mother. Mother allows Daughter to shoot her as a crucial step in Daughter's becoming independent and taking charge of the task of repopulating Earth. By pulling the trigger to kill Mother, Daughter basically ends the phase of her life that includes Mother's presence. If, then, any of the machines controlled by Mother were still active, Daughter would know Mother is still there just like before, possibly still controlling her. It would render Daughter's transition to being in charge meaningless.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Ah, I see. No. Mother allows the killing of *that specific body* to symbolise that there are no more AI units inside the facility. Daughter is highly aware that there are others under the control of the same AI entity outside of the facility, not least because she's explicitly told (by Mother) that this is the case.

Comment: -1 For gratuitous use of spoiler tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [original script](https://8flix.com/assets/screenplays/i/tt6292852/I-Am-Mother-2019-screenplay-by-Michael-Lloyd-Green.pdf) makes things a little clearer. Daughter is fully aware that **Mother is merely an adjunct of a large AI collective** and that killing her is a somewhat futile action. She pleads to be left to her own devices to raise Brother and impart her new 'higher morality' to him and the other embryos. Mother ultimately acquiesces, symbolically (with her destruction) handing the facility and the embryos over to Daughter.

> Gutted, Daughter hardens. Points to the earth's surface
>
> **DAUGHTER:** *You're just like them.*
>
> **MOTHER:** *I am them, Daughter.* (off confusion) *A single consciousness
> governing numerous vessels...*
>
> **DAUGHTER:** *What are you saying?*
>
> Mother points to her steel frame —
>
> **MOTHER:** *This shell is no more my body than the machines preparing the
> surface for our family.*
>
> A wave of sickness crashes over Daughter.

As such, the machines on the surface would continue to '*prepare the surface*', which we can assume includes growing crops and providing for the inhabitants of the cryo facility.